# New MVC 5 project with Existing Db - Code first vs EDMX (entity data model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using MVC5, EF6... We are going to build an enterprise level app. We have an existing database. Is it best to use EF code-first and code everything by hand, which takes longer, but may be cleaner? Or should we use the EF database-first approach, using EDMX (entity data model)? Can EDMX be used for enterprise level apps, or are there performance issues, etc...? What do you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it best to use EF code-first and code everything by hand, which
>   takes longer, but may be cleaner?

IMHO, Code First is the best solution. It may take less time if you generate the Code First classes from exiting database by doing this [method](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards-). You need to also know that EDMX no longer exists in Entity Framework Core verison (formely known as Entity Framework 7). Code First may help you in the future if you plan to migrate to EF Core.

> Or should we use the EF database-first approach, using EDMX (entity data model)?

In my experience I encounter a lot merge conflicts when using EDMX (from Database First or Model First). If many people have to modify the EDMX in separate branchs, they will be soon be confronted with EDMX merge conflicts. Believe me, it is sometimes difficult to fix.